# Retrieve Firebase data who have specific child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please check my database image. I want to select and display all users who have `parent = chris`

[my database image](https://www.mediafire.com/view/a1odbpjdm65t2l6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the users that contain `parent : chris`, you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

reference.orderByChild("parent").equalTo("chris").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String name = datas.child("name").getValue(String.class);
   String key = datas.getKey();
    }
 }
   @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     throw databaseError.toException();
  }
 });
```

`orderByChild.equalTo` is a query that will retrieve all the nodes that contain `parent` equal to `chris`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as a android studio question I assume you are using the Firebase SDK.
You should check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), where they explain how you can query in a lot of languages with very nice examples.